# How to get column names when using OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset

I'm working on transforming some data that is contained within an EXCEL file, and I'm using OPENROWSET to do this. I can get the data with a `select *` type syntax, but I'm not getting any column names back in the results.
In this case, the result is one simple value that I'd like to use or place in a temp table or variable.

However, this value comes back as NULL in the last select statement. What am I missing here? Is the SQL syntax in the OLEDB call correct (it seems to be limited)?

```
declare @catalog_ID nvarchar(100);
set @catalog_ID = (select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;HDR=yes;Database=D:\[my-worksheet].xlsx','SELECT * FROM [ru_RU$a3:b3]') )
select @catalog_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the column names back from your OPENROWSET call, I think you just need to change `HDR=yes` to `HDR=no`.

Good luck.